# Remove all places that starts with known part till some known end part

Tags: java, regex, string, str-replace

I have some text (JSON) where I need to remove all parts that starts with known text and ends with some known text. Please help me build a regex to remove all that.

String input, part from JSON:

```json
"oge": "GOF",
"original": {
  "report": true,
  "tier": "IA"
},
"pertinentNegative": false,
"populationFrequency": {
  "externalLinks": {
    "7-2-A-T": "https://x.d.org/s/7-d-A-T?dataset=s"
  },
  "maxPop": "South Asian",
  "maxPopAC": 1,
  "maxPopAN": 30,
  "maxPopFreq": 3.276,
  "overallPopAC": 1,
  "overallPopAN": 23,
  "overallPopFreq": 4.22,
  "source": "gnomAD"
}
```

Known start part : "externalLinks" 
Known end part : "maxPop"

I need to remove all that starts with "externalLinks" till "maxPop".

Output after regex work:

```json
"oge": "GOF",
"original": {
  "report": true,
  "tier": "IA"
},
"pertinentNegative": false,
"populationFrequency": {
  "maxPop": "South Asian",
  "maxPopAC": 1,
  "maxPopAN": 30,
  "maxPopFreq": 3.276,
  "overallPopAC": 1,
  "overallPopAN": 23,
  "overallPopFreq": 4.22,
  "source": "gnomAD"
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using JAVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "*replaceAll*" method with the following pattern:

```
\"externalLinks\"[\s\S]+?(?=\"maxPop\")
```

This will match you every occurrence of `"externalLinks"` followed by any character, till next occurrence of "*"maxPop"*" (not included in the match). The lazy operator (`?`) will allow you to match the least amount possible of characters. Replace every match with the empty string.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/LrORHj/1).